# Limiting processing time of request for WCF or ASMX webservice

Tags: web-services, wcf, asmx, .net-4.8

Let say I have a webservice (WCF and ASMX .net framework 4.8) which is hosted on IIS 10. Webservice has a method with this content:

```
    public CustomerListResponse Get(CustomerListRequest request)
{
    //sleep for 1 hour
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    
    return new CustomerListResponse();
}
```

The line that is performing sleep on thread is just to show that there is code that in some cases can take long time.

What I'm looking is setting or way to limit allowed processing time for example to one minute and error returned to client. I want the processing be killed by IIS/WCF/ASMX if the execution time will exceed one minute.

Unfortunately I didn't found a way in IIS for that. Also I don't have access to client code to set this limit on other side - change is possible only on server side.

What I tried:

- on binding for WCF there is couple of properties openTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" - I set them all but it didn't work. Code can still process for long time.
- `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" executionTimeout="60" />` - also didn't work

I don't have other ideas how to achieve that, but I believe there should be some solution to be able control how long we want to spend on processing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the timeout on both client-side and server-side.

Client-side:

**SendTimeout** is used to initialize OperationTimeout, which manages the entire interaction of sending a message (including receiving a reply message in a request-reply case). This timeout also applies when a reply message is sent from the CallbackContract method.
**OpenTimeout and CloseTimeout** are used to open and close channels (when no explicit timeout value is passed).
**ReceiveTimeout** not used.

Server-side:

**Send, open, and close timeouts** are the same as on the client side (for callbacks).
**ReceiveTimeout** is used by the ServiceFramework layer to initialize idle session timeouts.

Comment: What if there is no access to client code? Is then the way to set hard limit on IIS side?

Comment: In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site ,then Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you will see Connection Time-out. Or change it in config file like this: `<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>`